# proper rewriterule paramaeters for php to xml

Tags: mod-rewrite

What is the correct rewrite rule to use from php to xml.

sample:

```
podcast.php - podcasts.xml  
ringtones.php - ringtones.xml  
and so on...
```

i currently have this on my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^podcasts.xml$ podcasts.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^(.*?)\.xml$      $1.php [L]
```

But this will replace all .xml requests.

Comment: thanks..,don't worry i put this files on a folder together with this htaccess rule.

Comment: OK but if your path to this is `http://yourdomain/path/somefile.xml` then the easiest thing to do is to leave this in `DOCROOT/.htaccess` and change the rule to: `RewriteRule   ^path/(.*?)\.xml$ path/$1.php [L]`. If you move it to `DOCROOT/path/.htaccess` then you need to change the rewrite base to `/path` :)